# QGIS Data doubled in the attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I was working on two different layers which I ultimately combined together using the "union" tool. 
However, I now have twice the information in the attribute table as shown in the picture.
Any insight on how I can quickly delete the repeated rows?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each row represents a feature, it looks like you have duplicated some of your features.  If these features have identical geometry (ie you didn't edit the geometry in one file and not the other - and that explains why you appear to have half the number of features in the map as they sit directly one on top of the other), you can go:

```
MMQGIS->Modify->Delete Duplicate Geometries
```

You may need to install the MMQGIS plugin via `Plugins->Manage and install plugins...`

You can also type 'duplicate' into the Prcoessing toolbox search bar and you will find another couple of tools that do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (a bit rudimentary maybe, but very simple) could be to create a new field, let's name it "num" for example, Just put $rownum as the expression. 
Then, go to Select by expression and type:  "num" % 2 = 1
It will select the uneven rows. Then, click edit, and delete selected objects. 
In your case as I see the repetition is alwas the same (each feature repeated once) this should work.

Comment: This is a risky strategy, you may end up deleting data you should have kept. Be sure to take a close look and make sure you don't need those rows before deleting.

Comment: You are right. But this strategy works if, as it looks like, each row is doubled with no exceptions. In any case, of course is important to take a close look before deleting. Thanks!